# Different variations of point-to-zone mapping

Tags: qgis, interpolation, vector-grid, demography

I have created a grid of 1Km2 over some census zones. Now, for each cell of the grid, I need to provide some characterization of it: population, socio-econ, etc. coming from the census zones.

So, some cells will be completely inside some census zone, some others will cover two or more zones, etc. (see figure).

[image]

How can I interpolate the data from the zones to the grid in the best (mathematical) way?